# constexprify behavioral sequencing function

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, c++17

I am writing a simple behavioral model engine for a project of mine. I'm now stuck at trying to make one particular function constexpr.

**QUESTION IS AT THE BOTTOM, THE REST IS BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

### Short explanation of how the framework works

A behavioral node can return one of three states:

```
enum class State { Fail, Success, Running };
```

The default leaf nodes always return one of theese three states:

```
constexpr inline auto success() { return []{ return State::Success; }; }                                 
constexpr inline auto fail()    { return []{ return State::Fail;    }; }                                 
constexpr inline auto running() { return []{ return State::Running; }; }
```

There are different operations that can be performed, for example negation:

```
constexpr inline auto operator~(auto rule) {
  return [rule]{                                                                                         
    const auto result = rule();                                                                          
    return result == State::Fail ? State::Success :                                                      
           result == State::Success ? State::Fail :                                                      
           State::Running;                                                                               
  };                                                                                                     
}
```

...and other logical operations:

```
constexpr inline auto operator&&(auto left, auto right) {
  return [left, right]{
    const auto lresult = left();
    const auto rresult = right();
    return (lresult == State::Fail || rresult == State::Fail) ? State::Fail :
           (lresult == State::Success && rresult == State::Success) ? State::Success :
           State::Running;
  };
}
```

Finally there is the evaluation function, which is very simple:

```
inline State execute(auto rule) {
  return rule();
}
```

### Example

```
CHECK( State::Success == execute(success() && success()) );
CHECK( State::Fail    == execute(success() && fail()) );
```

### Example

I did not have access to a C++17 compiler when writing this example so can't actually compile and test it.

Here we use a mixture of rules possible to evaluate at compile time, and some for run time. A dude walks up to a locked door and tries to open it, if he has a key is decided at compile time.

```
auto walking                 = false;
auto door_open               = false;
auto is_at_door              = false;
constexpr auto dude_has_key  = false;

constexpr auto unlock_door = []{return []{
    return dude_has_key ? State::Success : State::Fail;
};};

const auto walk_to_door = [&]{return []{
    if(walking) { // Stop at the door
        walking    = false;
        is_at_door = true;
        return State::Success;
    }
    if(!is_at_door) {
        walking = true;
        return State::Running;
    }
    return State::Fail; // Cannot walk through the door
};};

const auto open_door = [&]{return []{
    // We want to compile-time check if the door is locked
    // hence we never check for that condition here.
    if(!door_open) {
        door_open = true;
    }
    return State::Success
};};

const auto rules = sequence({walk_to_door, unlock_door && open_door});
CHECK( State::Running == execute(rules) ); // Walking to door
CHECK( State::Fail    == execute(rules) ); // Cannot unlock door
```

### Example

I did not have access to a C++17 compiler when writing this example so can't actually compile and test it.

```
struct MyThing {
    static constexpr bool PropertyA = true;
    static constexpr int  PowerLevel = 42;
};

struct YourThing {
    static constexpr bool PropertyA = false;
    static constexpr int  PowerLevel = 43;
};

constexpr auto has_property_a(auto thing) {
    return []{ return decltype(thing)::PropertyA ? State::Success :: State::Fail; };
}

constexpr auto has_minimum_power_level(auto thing, auto min_pl) {
    return []{ return decltype(thing)::PowerLevel > min_pl ? Satet::Success ::State::Fail; };
} 

template<typename ThingA, typename ThingB>
constexpr auto rule = sequence({
    has_property_a(ThingA{}), 
    has_minimum_power_level(ThingB{}, 9000)
});
execute(sequence({rule<MyThing,YourThing>, __some_runtime_rule});
```

### Current problem

...is the sequencing function which is supposed to pass the following tests

```
CHECK( State::Success       == execute(sequence({success(), success(), success()})) );
CHECK( State::Fail          == execute(sequence({success(), success(), fail()})) );
CHECK( State::Running       == execute(sequence({success(), success(), running()})) );
// last (fail) never evaluated due to 2nd being running
CHECK( State::Running       == execute(sequence({success(), running(), fail()})) );
```

in other words, it returns `State::Success` when all of the nodes in the sequence returns `State::Success`. Should it encounter a `State::Running` it "waits" there until `State::Success` or `State::Fail`. A `State::Fail` fails the whole sequence.

The current make-the-tests-pass-implementation of this function looks like

```
using Rule = std::function<State()>;
inline auto sequence(std::initializer_list<Rule> rules) {
  return [rules]{
    auto result = State::Success;
    for(auto next : rules) {
      const auto next_result = next();
      result = (result == State::Success && next_result == State::Success) ? State::Success :
               (result == State::Success && next_result == State::Running) ? State::Running :
               State::Fail;
      if(result == State::Fail || result == State::Running) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return State::Success;
  };
}
```

**Now how do I make this constexpr?**

Comment: Future implementation is some event driven design so that the tree doesn't have to be re-evaluated every time, feel free to hint on this subject too if you see any obvious solutions.

Comment: Your description of how the running state works is at odds with your implementation of sequence and &&. Is `sequence({success(), running(), success()})` meant to return Success or Running?

Comment: @Caleth that would return running, since it never checks the next in the sequence until all up until the current one are success.

Comment: As I made more and more edits, my post became more and more similar to @Caleth's, nothing I can add here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sequence is just meant to be repeated application of &&, then you can specify it with a fold

Allows empty `sequence()` (which returns equivalent of `success`)

```
template <typename ... Rules>
constexpr auto sequence(Rules ... rules)
{
    return [rules...](){ return State::Success && ... && rules(); };
}
```

Or require at least one rule

```
template <typename First, typename ... Rules>
constexpr auto sequence(First first, Rules ... rules)
{
    return [first, rules...](){ return first() && ... && rules(); };
}
```

Comment: In my brain this works, I will test it out later when I get home from work.

Comment: This does not work. It doesn't stop at `running` since the precedence of the special rules of the && operator is lost when overloading it. The following test case fails:
`CHECK( running == execute(sequence(success, running, fail)) );`

Comment: Also the syntax is wrong, the following compiles on gcc 7.0
`[first, rules...](){ return (first && ... && rules)(); };`

Comment: I didn't end up using this solution but you made me realize that I actually just wanted to chain boolean operators. If you're interested the tiny lib I made is here https://github.com/simonvpe/moar-rulez